# Dust after staining and poly advice

Tags: woodworking, wooden-furniture, polyurethane, stain

Two questions: How should I prepare for applying poly to new stain? I am refinishing a wood veneer table top. I stripped it back to the wood, and I have stained it with Old Masters Wiping Stain, following the directions to brush it on and wipe it off. That was 24 hours ago in perfect drying weather. It looks good, and I am about to apply a poly to finish it. I noticed that some brown comes off when I wipe my hand over it; I think it's dust, and it's definitely stain-colored. Should I use mineral spirits or just a tac cloth to wipe it down? Is that dust normal?
Second question: Do you recommend thinning the poly and wiping it on in thin, thin coats, or can I go with just straight poly? I am going to use Zar Uptra Fast Drying Poly: Clear Antique Flat. There is a lot of different advice out there.
Thank you everyone!

Comment: Should this be migrated to wood-working?

Comment: @James, It's on topic here, but it would probably get more answers over on woodworking.

Comment: @Doresoom thats what I was thinking, I have been over there a bit and the quality of knowledge is pretty impressive.

Comment: I'd be happy to move it over to woodworking, but I don't know how! Where is that? How can I move it? I tried tagging it, but maybe that's not enough? Thanks.

Comment: @James, Boyd: I flagged it for moderator attention, and posted a question to Meta for best procedures in future similar situations. http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/questions/1071/should-we-migrate-on-topic-questions-that-are-better-suited-to-woodworking